# Hard drive does not display in Ubuntu USB live session

Tags: live-usb, windows-10

I am new to Ubuntu. I reviewed the suggested answers for my problem, but they did not seem to apply.

Background:
I could not boot into Windows 10 and research directed me to Ubuntu, so I downloaded the Ubuntu live USB and it booted up smoothly. However when I checked the disk drives (hoping to access photos and select documents) there were three options:

1. CD/DVD
2. Thumb drive
3. Loop device.

Can anyone offer further instructions as to how I can get my photos back?

Comment: If Windows is not booting it may have chkdsk flag set or still be hibernated. And then the Linux NTFS driver will not auto mount it. You may be able to manually mount in read only mode. But drive must be set to AHCI, not RAID which some systems use. You should add AHCI driver first to Windows, but temporarily change back & then fix Windows. Or it could be hard drive failure, does UEFI/BIOS show drive? Also if SSD, it may need firmware update and UEFI updates to be seen.  Always best to have good backups of anything you consider important.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however, I am unfamiliar with some of the lingo,e.g. AHCI RAID drive, mounting.
I had backed up the files to an external hard drive but when I uploaded (as a copy) to OneDrive, they disappeared from my external and did not appear on OneDrive. Microsoft has not been of assistance. I am hoping that I have extra copies of the photos on the computer I am now trying to access.

Comment: Please review your computer manual & UEFI settings. It should offer AHCI, RAID, perhaps Intel or the very old IDE as options for drive. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express#Comparison_with_AHCI  Does UEFI show drive in list of drives/hardware connected?

Comment: Have a look in"disks" for the HDD. if it is there and has a triangle by it, click the triangle to mount. If using 16.04 click the upper left corner and type disks, for 18.04 try the lower LH corner and type disks.

Comment: Thanks for the continued guidance.  I have checked the manual and AHCI is the identified drive, and it is listed in the Boot Menu; however, when I load Ubuntu Live and check DISKS, it is not visible. When I selected the (loading Ubuntu) option to load the HDD, a number of error messages were generated, ultimately saying that it failed to load.
Once Ubuntu Live is launched and I check DISKS inside the live environment, the HDD is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

- While booting into ubuntu live, you can search an app named 'Disks' after pressing window key.
- After opening the app choose the hard drive from the left column and select the partition you want to access. Below that there will be 3 buttons, the first one is to mount the partition.
- After you have mounted the partition, you can open 'Files' and click 'other locations' to view the partition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. Nothing happens when I press the windows key and I do not see an app named "Disks". I continue to see references to "Mounting partitions or drives" but I do not know what that means.